# Find the number of integer solutions to $x_1+x_2-x_3=-4$, such that $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0$ and $x_3\leq 10$

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of integer solutions to $x_1+x_2-x_3=-4$, such that $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0$ and $x_3\leq 10$

I'm not sure how to deal with the constraint that $x_3\leq 10$

I tried rearranging as $x_1+x_2=x_3-4$, where $-4\leq x_3-4\leq 6$

then took the sum as $\sum_{i=-4}^6{i-2+1 \choose 2}$

I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Hint: Note that $x_3$ can only be $4$, $5$, or $6$ due to the constraint that all are nonnegative. That simplifies the problem quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say something like let $y_3 = 10-x_3$

Then we can say we can rewrite our problem to be:

$x_1 + x_2 + y_3 - 10 = -4$

or $x_1 + x_2 + y_3 = 6$

With $x_1,x_2,y_3 \ge 0$

Now we have a problem that looks more familiar.

And this is the number of lattice points on a triangle, which we can show equals

$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 7 = 28$

Comment: Ive never seen how to compute for $\geq$, simply with $x_1+...+x_k=n$ where all are non negative. Also if $y_3-10=x_3$ why did you change the equality to an inequality when substituting it?

Comment: You are correct, it should be equality.  I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

1) Clearly $x_3 \ne 1,2,3 $: $0$ solutions

2) If $x_3=4 \implies x_1+x_2 = 0 \implies (0,0)$ is the only 1 solution

3) If $x_3=5 \implies x_1+x_2 = 1 \implies (0,1), (1,0)$ 2 solutions

4) If $x_3=6 \implies x_1+x_2 = 2 \implies (0,2), (2,0), (1,1) $ 3 solutions

5) If $x_3=7 \implies x_1+x_2 = 3 \implies (0,3), (1,2), (2,1), (3,0)$ 4 solutions

6) If $x_3=8 \implies x_1+x_2 = 4 \implies (0,4), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,0)$ 5 
solutions

7) If $x_3=9 \implies x_1+x_2 = 5 \implies (0,5), (1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1), (5,0)$ 6 solutions

8) If $x_3=10 \implies x_1+x_2 = 6 \implies (0,6), (1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1), (6,0)$ 7 solutions

All in all there are $1+2+...+7=28$ possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

You get the bounds $4 \leq x_3 \leq 10$. (The lower ones comes from $x_1+x_2 \geq 0$.

Now, think about the equation $x_1 + x_2 = x_3-4$ for each possible value of $x_3-4 = 0,1,2,\dots, 6$. Draw it to gridded plane (it's a line):

[image]

They form a triangle

$$1+2+\dots +7 = \frac{7 \times 8}{2} = 28$$

Answer (score 0):

Well if $x_3\leq 10$ and $x_1+x_2=x_3-4$ then $x_1+x_2\leq 6$;  So $$(0,6),(0,5),(0,4),(0,3),(0,2),(0,1),(1,5),(1,4),(1,3),(1,2),(1,1),(1,0),(2,4),(2,3),(2,2),(2,1),(2,0),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1),(3,0),(4,2),(4,1),(4,0),(5,1),(5,0),(6,0)$$ are solutions. There are 28.